# sqlsrv_query not returning anything

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am trying to run a sqlsrv_connect SELECT query, and I am having issues getting any information back. No matter what query I run, sqlsrv_num_rows always returns a null value. I have verified that my queries are correct in SQL Server Management studio.

Some sample code:

```
$connection_info = array("UID"=>"uid", "PWD"=>"pwd", "Database"=>"db");
$c = sqlsrv_connect("tcp:hostname", $connection_info);
if (!$c) {
   die(0);
}
$sql = "QUERY";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $c, $sql );
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result );
echo $sql . $row_count;
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: You need a specific cursor when you execute `sqlsrv_query()`, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010873/php-ms-sql-count-number-of-rows-is-empty/51012060#51012060) may help.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue. What version of PHP you are running?

Comment: Switching to mssql_connect, mssql_query, mssql_num_rows and mssql_fetch_array solved my problem. You must have required drivers installed with php to use these functions. mssql functions will work better for you if your web server is on a linux machine. [mssql vs sqlsrv](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-whats-the-difference-part-1/)

Comment: My server is on IIS. I am running php 7.3, so I cannot use mssql since it is not available on PHP >= 5.3. It is important for my task I use the latest version of php.

Comment: So based off of the answer given by Zhorov the solution was to add the `array("Scrollable" => 'static')` as an option to the sqlsrv_query call. That seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: @SA3709, if you want to get the count of the records, change the SQL statement to something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`, but if you want to check if the result set has rows, you may use `sqlsrv_has_rows()` with any type of cursor.

Comment: @Zhorov I legitimately just wanted to check if the result set had rows. When I execute the query I do not get any results. I get null. Putting the `array("Scrollable" => 'static')` gave me results and a non-null result from `sqlsrv_has_rows()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to put `array("Scrollable" => 'static')` as a configuration option for the select function.